# Can i build and compile react native via terminal?

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to compile and build my REACT native application via PHP code, there is the opportunity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-Native application is just an XCode project, so you can use existing CLI tools like `xcodebuild` or [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool).